# Sort dataframe by month and find the first non-zero value in each column for each month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I need to load a CSV with 200 columns, the first column is a date, into a pandas dataframe in python.  I need to sort through the data and return the first non-zero value for each month. Should I make separate dataframes or each month, and then search? What's the best way to approach this problem?

```
df = pd.read_csv('loaddata.csv')
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
df['Month']= pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DATE']).month


THe data looks like this:

Date    Data_1   Data_2  Data_3
1/d/y    0         0       1
2/d/y    0         1       2
3/d/y    2         6       0
1/d/y    5         3       45
2/d/y    20        7       90
3/d/y    25        12      18


Returns: 
      Data_1   Data_2   Data_3
Jan     5         3       1
Feb     20        7       2
Mar     2         6       18
```

Comment: The first non zero value for each month for each column or what? Please try to make a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You got an error for `Feb`, column `Data_2`: the first non-zero is 1, not 7.

---

Here's one way to do it:

```
def first_non_zero(col):
    """Return the first non-zero value of a column, or nan if the column is all-zero"""
    head = col[col != 0].head(1)
    return np.nan if head.empty else head.values

df.groupby('Month').apply(lambda group: group[['Data_1', 'Data_2', 'Data_3']].apply(first_non_zero)) \
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Result:

```
       Data_1  Data_2  Data_3
Month                        
1           5       3       1
2          20       1       2
3           2       6      18
```